# Is there any method to replace specific data from column without breaking its structure or spliting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Hi there i am trying to figure out how to replace a **specific data of csv** file. i have a file which is base or *location data* of *id's.*
https://store8.gofile.io/download/5b031959-e0b0-4dbf-aec6-264e0b87fd09/service%20block.xlsx (sheet 2 had data ).

The file which i want to replace data using id is below
https://store8.gofile.io/download/6e13a19a-bac8-4d16-8692-e4435eed2a08/Serp.csv
Highlighted part need to be deleted after filling location.
[image: Deleting after filling location]

```
import pandas as pd 

df1= pd.read_excel("serp.xlsx", header=None)
df2= pd.read_excel("flocnam.xlsx", header=None)
df1 = df1[0].str.split(";", expand=True)



df1[4] = df1[4].apply(lambda x: v[-1] if (v := x.split()) else "")

df2[1] = df2[1].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])


m = dict(zip(df2[1], df2[0]))
df1[4]= df1[4].replace(m)


print(df1)
df1.to_csv ("test.csv")
```

It worked but not how i wanted.
https://store8.gofile.io/download/c0ae7e05-c0e2-4f43-9d13-da12ddf73a8d/test.csv

[image: Test working but need some help more]

trying to replace it like this.(desired output)

[image]

Thank you for being Supportive community❤️

Comment: Very confusing explanation. What are you trying to replace? What is your expected output? Please consider going through [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=minimum+reproducible+example).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you simply need to specify the separator `;`

```
>>> df.to_csv(‘test.csv’, sep=‘;’, index_label=False)
```

Comment: Thank you danail. code worked. Thats why i love this community. ❤️